# Is it possible to suppress an Error message in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

in my powerapp I am sorting my gallery by a Status field

It works fine, but an Error is displayed in a Red Banner at the top:
[image]

This is the code inside the OnSelect of the Status column header:

```
Set(
    gvSortDesc,
    !gvSortDesc
);
Set(
    gvSortCol,
    "Status"
);
SortByColumns(
    colGalleryContents,
    gvSortCol,
    If(
        gvSortDesc,
        SortOrder.Descending,
        SortOrder.Ascending
    )
)
```

The Status column is a Choice field in my SharePoint list.
Other columns such as Implementation (Date) or Title (Text) sort fine with no errors.
As you can see in the above image, the sorting works well enough,

So how can I simply ignore/throw away that error?

How can I  suppress that Red banner from showing?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to ignore the error, you can "catch" it locally by wrapping the SortByColumns in an IfError expression as shown below. That will handle the error locally, and ensure that it is not bubbled up to the app, where it would show the error banner.

```
IfError(
    SortByColumns(
        colGalleryContents,
        gvSortCol,
        If(
            gvSortDesc,
            SortOrder.Descending,
            SortOrder.Ascending
        )
    ),
    colGalleryContents // unsorted
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it all up with an ifError and then filter the Error message out if it contains the string "column 'status' does" or something similar, depending on your error message.

Referencing to 9:08min "Suppressing Power Apps error messages" in this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zc4mE_4U7lI&t=548s)

Comment: thanks for your answer, please would you add some detail such as a code snippet and how it would solve the problem.